# Is there a reason why there are no other human civilisations in The Long Earth?

Tags: the-long-earth

I've just read *The Long Earth* and *The Long War* and the point is made that Datum Earth is the only place that Homo Sapiens evolved.  Is there an explanation given for this in the later books?

Comment: It is because the writer knows a species can only evolve once in on place.  A species which evolved on another planet would not be Homo Sapiens. No matter how much like Homo sapiens it might be due to convergent evolution, it would not be the species Homo sapiens, it would not be a member of Genus Homo, it would not a member of the Order Primates, nor the Class of Mammals, nor the Phylum of Chordata, nor of the Kingdom Animalia, because those are subdivisions of Earth life. So it is because the book is biologically realistic.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, you should make it an answer.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Except that there are trees, plants, insects, grasses, etc that are common *across a vast array of stepwise universes*. How did those evolve? Or are you saying that they evolved independently on each Earth, but that humanity is somehow special in this fictional universe

Comment: @M.A.Golding - There's also *leakage* between the worlds. Sufficient, perhaps to explain why there are common plants but not sufficient to explain why there aren't any humans elsewhere

Comment: @Valroum  So this is an alternate universe story?  The species Homo sapiens appeared about 300,000 years ago and developed civilization about 5,000 years ago.  Possibly all the other alternate universe  branched off more than 300,000 years ago and contain species of planets and animals which evolved more than 300,000 years ago.  And maybe universes which diverged more recently and do contain Homo sapiens are not reachable for some reason.

Comment: I think there was an explanation, maybe even in the first book, but don't remember it well. That people from other worlds could travel between them long time ago and it changed everything?

Comment: I would suspect that while an isolated seed, or egg sac can produce a successful incursion to a new universe (all other things being equal), an isolated human or two is going to die young without producing more humans.  It takes a large group to survive and thrive, and the number of natural steppers or humans that have leaked through has never been large enough to do so (until "Step Day").

Comment: @Mithoron  I thought I'd read something similar so I went back over the first book, but the only thing i could find was in chapter 32: Nelson Azikiwe explains that he was the leader of an archaeological programme that excavated over two thousand versions of Olduvai and other likely sites and only found very early hominids "There was nothing past the australopithecines, the Lucies. The cradles of mankind were empty".